# Unbundle Windows Store App

Tags: localization, windows-store-apps, windows-store

We need to make changing the language possible in our Windows Store application. Currently it works fine when debugging, but when downloaded from Windows Store, only some languages work. This is because App Bundle seems to have been selected for the app deployment. Only the languages installed to users Windows are downloaded from Windows Store within the app.

What would be the best way to get all languages working? Since app bundle has already been made, it seems that this can't be undone (?). Even if I manage to unbundle the app, it seems that Windows Store wouldn't accept .appx -packages after the bundle has once been sent to the store.

I also can't find a way to remove app package from Windows Store so that it would accept unbundled app (and that Visual Studio would permit publishing unbundled app)

Or is there a way to force all languages to everyone even when using app bundles? I know it's not what's it's intended for, but in this case I regret that app bundle is used and would like to revert it.

Comment: I recall seeing in the app store (cannot remember where) that once you "bundle" your app package you must continue to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the app has been released as a bundle, there's currently no way to update it with app package (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh923027.aspx).

There's no way to force the app bundle to download all languages, as it's internals are not build to handle such scenario.

What you could try to do is that you rename the old app (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694077.aspx), release the old name, and reserve it again and publish the package now as app package. I haven't tried this, so I can't guarantee it works.